# Can not searching from small letters in bootgrid.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-bootgrid

Please help me because there was no question related to bootgrid.js in stack overflow japanese version.

I want to use small letters on search.
but can't it. not working?

"caseSensitive" and "characters" setting is default value. As how to use, Table cell have japanese or english phrases.

In japanese case, No problem. but, Not working when searching for in english phrase(capital letters is no problem).
This issue happend in small letters.

[for example 1]

Want to search "restaurant".

1) Typing "r" key. => not working.

2) Typing "e" key. => display result.(working start in this step)

Probably, this issues is happend that only single character(above (1)). but, "characters" setting is default value.

[for example 2]

There is phrase "fan fun".

Type "f" : not working.

Type "fa" : not working.

Type "fu" : working.

Have i misunderstand anything?
Please teach me about how to resolve.

Comment: Add your current code to your question, then we can help better